# Expose methods do be used by another class

Tags: c#, callback, action

On a class method I have the following:

```
public class Test {
  public void SignIn() {
    var authentication = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    userService.SignInUser(username, /* Expose the authentication.SignIn() method */);
  }
}
```

"authentication" has 2 methods: void SignIn() and Int32 SignOut().

The UserService class is:

```
public class UserService {
  public void SignInUser() {
    // Get user
    // Sign In user using HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn().
    // Log use sign in
  }
}
```

In SignInUser method I want to use HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn().

But I do not want the SignInUser method to "know" anything about Authentication class.

I need to only exposed the method SignIn to be used ... The same with Int32 SignOut.

I think I should use an Action / Function / Delegate? I am not sure how to do this ...

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Just did ... Is more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see! That's easy.

```
    public class Test
    {
        public void SignIn() {
            var authentication = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            UserService.SignInUser(username, () => authentication.SignIn(), () => authentication.SignOut());
          }
    }


    public class UserService
    {
        public void SignInUser(Action onSigningIn, Func<int> onSigningOut)
        {
            // I don't check here if onSigningIn is null or not... that's all upon you
            onSigningIn();
            int n = onSigningOut();
        }
    }
```

---

this is just a simplified form of how actions called (if only one method called):

```
() => authentication.SignIn()
```

it equals to:

```
() => { authentication.SignIn(); }
```

(if you have Resharper, it would even suggested such 'upgrade')

for Functions you can have the following:

```
() => { 
    /*some line of code*/
    /*some more line of code*/
    return "some value";
}
```

and finally, if you are passing some value to the Function/Action:

```
v => { 
    /*some line of code*/
    /*some more line of code*/
    return "some value calculated basicly on v";
}
```

with a definition of that Action as:

```
SignInUser (..., Action<int> onSigningIn, ...)
```

*P.S. Just spend a bit time to get more familiar with Actions and Functions -- and you are golden! he he*

If you are familiar with javascript, then Actions and Functions generally work and look similar to clusures.

Comment: Just one more question: what if I want to expose a property from Test into UserService? That would be a delegate?

Comment: No. No needs in delegates at all. The Func expression looks like this way (that's like you would just have a common method body): v => { return SomeOfMyProperties; }, which would simply transformed into v => SomeOfMyProperties.
But. I would rather not recommend to do that with properties as that might be a bit confusing in future, as you kind of passing a property, but with 'delayer access', as its value will be evaluated and obtained later, but not at the moment when you call the SignInUser method.